# Can we use swagger with spring boot 1.3 and java 6?

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am writing an Api and I need to do documentation using swagger. I am using spring boot 1.3.5 because application server is old and has java 6 configured cannot upgrade to 8 as of now. Can we use springfox swagger with java 6?

Answer (score 2):

In the [current version](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/379f0ce84dae7fc70ea759b62ab0837d2c666ac1/build.gradle#L32) of Springfox is specified jdkVersion = 1.8, so you are out of luck. But slightly older versions like 1.0.1, [should be compatible](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/13cf94a2bcd34d6203e16108e8f18c0d50948c5b/build.gradle#L31). Look at the values for `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility`